# How can I loop through specific elements of a list in Bash?

Tags: bash, file-processing

I have a list of files stored in a variable obtained by entering

```
files="./*.fasta"
```

I would like to create a for loop that will loop through: the first 200 elements,  elements 201-400, elements 401-578, for example.

How can I achieve this? I tried something like

```
for file in $files[1-200]; do 
    echo $file
done
```

but clearly this does not work.

Comment: is there something that differentiate those elements from the other ones???

Comment: No, the split is entirely arbitrary. I just want to split the files up so I can run multiple batches simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a variable to populate a list of files is not recommended. The best way to do it would be using arrays!

You need to enable a shell option to avoid null glob expansion by doing `shopt -s nullglob` so that if no files are found the for-loop exits gracefully. The example below shows iterating over the 200 files at a time. You could change the indices as needed to print from 200-400 and 400-600 as needed in the for-loop.

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(*.fasta)

if (( "${#files}" >= 200 )); then
    for ((i=0; i<200; i++)); do
        printf '%s\n' "${files[i]}"
    done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the array advice. Should I understand the null glob bit as avoiding the usual error I see where no matching file is found and bash attempts to run whatever program I'm using with just "/*.fasta" as the input?

Comment: @chrispbio : Exactly yes!

Answer (score 1):

Put them in an array, then use substring expansion to get batches of files.

```
files=(./*.fasta)
for ((i=0; i< ${#fasta[*]}; i+=200)); do
    process "${files[@]:i:200}" &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be approach differently. Instead of using a for loop you may use `find` and `xargs`:

```
find * -name '*.fasta' -maxdepth 0 -print0 | xargs -0 -n 200 -P 0 echo
```

`find` passes every file name to `xargs` which in turn spawns a process (`-P 0`) for every 200 input files (`-n 200`).

This one-liner uses `-print0` and `-0` flags just in case your filenames contain whitespace.

The for loop construct is less than ideal in this scenario.

Alternatively, you might use a while loop and a readarray builtin:

```
find * -name '*.fasta' -maxdepth 0 | while readarray -n 3 a && [[ ${#a} -ne 0 ]]
do
    echo ${a[@]}
done
```